# wrong operation result in shift right arithmetic in verilog

Tags: verilog

If I simply write following code:

```
module TOP;

wire [31:0] a = 32'b11111111_11111111_11000000_00000000;
wire [31:0] b = 32'b00000000_00000000_00010000_00011111;

wire [4:0] shamt;
assign shamt = b[4:0];

wire signed [31:0] signed_a;
assign signed_a = a;

wire [31:0] output;
assign output = signed_a >>> b;
```

This gives a correct result which is 11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111

However, if I use code that uses module, it always generates wrong result:

```
module TOP;

reg [31:0] a = 32'b11111111_11111111_11000000_00000000;
reg [31:0] b = 32'b00000000_00000000_00010000_00011111;

wire [31:0] out;

ALU alu(
    .A(a),
    .B(b),
    .C(out)
);

initial
begin
    #10 $display("out: %b\n", out);
    #10 $display("outout: %b\n", alu.outout);
    #10 $display("C: %b\n", alu.C);
end

endmodule

module ALU (
    input [31:0] A,
    input [31:0] B,
    output [31:0] C
);

wire signed [31:0] outout;

wire [31:0] signed_a;
assign signed_a = A;

wire [4:0] shamt;
assign shamt = B[4:0];

assign outout = signed_a >>> shamt;

assign C = outout;

endmodule
```

In above code, all result from $display shows wrong value which is

00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001.

Why it doesn't generate correct value like first code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define signed_a as signed in the ALU module:

```
wire [31:0] signed_a;
```

should be

```
wire signed [31:0] signed_a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is down to simple typos.

In your second code you have places where you use `singed_a`, and others where you use `signed_a`. If you check the warnings from your compiler it will actually tell you this.

Basically your code ignores the input `A` because you are assigning it to a non-existent variable.

Secondly, your second code uses a bit shift (`>>`), not an arithmetic shift (`>>>`) so will not perform sign extension (see below).

---

<s>The result your second module calculates is exactly the correct result for the hardware you have described.</s>

`>>` is the bit shift operator, which performs zero filling. It doesn't matter whether the number is signed or unsigned, it will shift in zeros to the MSBs.

The `>>>` operator on the other hand is an arithmetic shift. This *will* perform sign extension, shifting in the MSB of the original number into the MSBs.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It was >>> not >>.

Even though I use >>> in the second code, it doesn't show correct result.